# JSON: Ignoring same-name records inside nested objects, and retrieving the-pair-name records outside

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I'm accessing a search API that gives json result like: [Free Search API](http://www.faroo.com/api?q=mean&start=1&length=50&l=en&src=web&i=false&f=json)

I want to retrieve only the records `title`, `kwic`, and `url` in the object `results` into my code. But the `title` and `url` in the object `related` are standing in the way.

I have tried doing some if function:

```
foreach ($json->results as $item) {
if (isset($item->kwic)) {
    $rss_item = array(
        'title' => $item->title,
        'kwic' => $item->kwic,
        'url' => $item->url,
    );
    array_push($desArray, $item->kwic);
}

else {
    return false;
}
array_push($rss_array, $rss_item);

for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
echo '<a href="' . $rss_array[$i]['url'] . '">' . $rss_array[$i]['title'] . '</a><a href="' . $rss_array [$i]['url'] . '" target="_blank">' . '<img src="http://corrupteddevelopment.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/open-new-tab-window-icon.jpg" width="15px" height="15px"></a><br/>';//LINE 66
echo '<hr/>';
echo '<p>' . $rss_array [$i]['kwic'] . '</p></br>';
}
```

It gave me partly results, and partly : `Notice: Undefined offset: 31 in C:\xampp\htdocs\MSP\SignIn\cariFree.php on line 66`. When I wrote:

```
if (isset($item->related)) {
return false}
```

It gave me entirely blank page.
What have I missed?
Thank you.

Here is the screen-shoot of the full code: [mycode.php](http://s13.postimg.org/s8bv6akzb/CODE4.png)

Comment: could you give us the entire code? because i don't see what $desArray is.

Comment: I have upload the screen-shoot of the entire code, the link to that image is on the last line of my question, thanks.

Comment: Your error is `on line 66` (`in C:\xampp\htdocs\MSP\SignIn\cariFree.php on line 66`), but you posted lines 18-31 and a linked image of lines 1-32?

Comment: I have deleted some lines so it would fit into one screen.. The line 66 is still the first echo function inside for loop..

Comment: `Undefined offset: 31` means that there is not a `$rss_array[31]`. You could change the loop on the line before to either `for ($i = 0; $i < count($rss_array); $i++) {` or to a `foreach ( $rss_array as $key => $value ) {` and then use `echo '<a href="' . $rss_array[$key]['url'] . '">' . $rss_array[$key]['title'] ....`

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code a bit, I think that this is what you actually should be doing, but I'm not sure since I dont have the entire code and don't really understand what your problem is (apart from bad coding).

```
<?php

//first off use arrays instead of objects:
$json = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ( $json['results'] as $item ) {
    if ( isset($item['kwic']) ) {
        //we can push $item into the rss_array directly
        array_push($rss_array, $item); #I assume you want this here instead of outside the loop
    }
    //I removed the else since it seemed completly stupid
}

foreach ( $rss_array as $item ) {
    echo '<a href="' . $item['url'] . '">' . $item['title'] . '</a><a href="' . $item['url'] . '" target="_blank">' . '<img src="http://corrupteddevelopment.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/open-new-tab-window-icon.jpg" width="15px" height="15px"></a><br/>';//LINE 66
    echo '<hr/>';
    echo '<p>' . $item['kwic'] . '</p></br>';
}
```

Comment: I have upload the screen-shoot of the entire code, the link to that image is on the last line of my question. Please take a look.. Thanks..